# Minimum value from a dictionary based on value in secondary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list and a dictionary:

```
lst = ['Boston', 'Denver']
dic = {'Atlanta': 0, 'Boston':100, 'Denver':160}
```

I want to find the dictionary key that has the lowest value provided the key is in the list. In this case, I want to return 'Boston' rather than 'Atlanta' since it is not contained in the list. How would I search for the minimum value efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```py
min(lst, key=dic.get)
```

Comment: Note that this requires that every item in the list be one of the dict keys. Use the other solutions if this is not the case.

Comment: When the key is missing, `dict.get` returns None, consider setting it to inf.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
k = min(dic.keys() & lst, key=dic.get)
print(k)
```

Prints:

```
Boston
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min()` with a key parameter that associates a value of `inf` to any key that doesn't appear in the list:

```py
min(dic.keys(), key=lambda x: dic[x] if x in lst else float('inf'))
```

This outputs:

```
Boston
```